# No fullscreen option with Vimeo embed (non-iFrame). Need a workaround

Tags: video, embed, fullscreen, vimeo

I am creating my own course page using Elfsight Accordion and Vimeo videos. The accordion doesn't accept an iFrame, but it will accept the old legacy Object embed for Vimeo. Example code below. However, the trouble is that there is no full screen button and I cannot seem to find a decent fix on the net.

Code:

```
<object width="100%" height="600">    
 <param name="movie" value="https://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXX">    
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">    
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">    
 <embed width="100%" height="600" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXX" class="vimeo-player" type="text/html" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">    
</object>
```

Even though the allow fullscreen option is set to true, it just doesn't work.
Anyone able to advise?

Comment: Have the same issue... did you find a solution?